# Dynamically add JPanel instances to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add precreated JPanel instances into a bigger JPanel into a JScrollPane, but I can't get it to work.

I'm using NetBeans to create the container, then using the context menu to include it into a scroll panel.

To add the JPanel at runtime I'm doing this:

```
ActivityPanel actPanel;

for(Reservation r: mainFrame.getKiosko().getReservations()) {
    if( r.getUser().equals(user)) {
        actPanel = new ActivityPanel(r.getActivity(),mainFrame);
        actPanel.setHour(r.getHour());
        Dimension actDim = new Dimension(600, 100);
        actPanel.setPreferredSize(actDim);
        actPanel.setMaximumSize(actDim);
        actPanel.setMinimumSize(actDim);

        pnlReservations.add(actPanel);                
    }
}
```

But it just is not working. Should I create the ScrollPanel at runtime? If so How should I do it?

`pnlReservation` has a BoxLayout by page axis.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the layout manager of `pnlReservations`?

Answer (score 1):

```
actPanel.setPreferredSize(actDim);
```

Don't try to manually control the preferred size of a component. The size of the panel should be determined by the components you add to the panel.

Same with your `pnlReservation`, don't hardcode a preferred size. The layout manager will determine its preferred size based on the preferred size of the components added to it.

Then the scrollbars will appear automatically as the preferred size of the `pnlReservation` dynamically changes when you add components to it.

Comment: It does not. Also, if I don't hardcore a size, it changes depending of the number of elements of the panel, and I don't want that.

Comment: @Xhark, If you don't want the size to change then use a GridLayout. Then all the components will be the same size. So first you create a panel using a BorderLayout. that you add to the scroll pane. Then you create second panel with the GridLayout that you add all the child panels to. Then you add this panel to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START of the first panel. Now all the panels will be the same size and will take up as much space as necessary and scrollbars will appear when required. Post a proper [mcve] if you need more help. Because we can't tell what is happening based a few lines of code.